# How I can add two menu in ActionBar Sherlock?

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock

I used [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/actionbarsherlock-custom-menu-list-navigation-fragments/) guide to create the main application menu.
Next, I added a button (three dots on the left) and the button I want to add another menu. It is important that the menu was different for each fragment

Code of button:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.actlist, menu);
   return true;
}
```

and xml file for this:

```
<menu xmlns:android=
  "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/act"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="title add"
    android:titleCondensed="add">
</item>
```

If I try to add a menu, it replaces the main menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items that don't fit in the actionbar are automatically added to the overflow, there is no need to create another menu. If you want to force the itmes to be in the overflow you can use android:showAsAction="never"

Comment: well it will be opened when you press the 3 dots, the new android design doesn't use the menu button anymore